# Problem with transparent background in modal view in react native

Tags: android, react-native, modal-dialog

I implemented a modal view in react native which is sliding in from the bottom (similar to the native modal view of iOS). I set the background of the modal view to transparent so the previous view is still visible, but the modal view is in focus. This is working fine and once it is open it also looks how I want it to look. My problem is, that the transparent background is also sliding in from the background and this does not look like a native implementation at all. What I want to achieve is, that the transparent background just appears while the modal view slides in from the bottom. Any idea on how to solve this?
My current code looks like this:

```
<Modal
    animationType="slide"
    transparent={true}
    statusBarTranslucent={true}
    visible={props.modalVisibility}
    onRequestClose={() => { props.setShowModal(false) }}
    style={{
      marginTop: 120,
      //backgroundColor:'grey'
    }}
  >
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor:'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'}}>
        ......
    </View>
</Modal>
```

Comment: That's because the `Modal` component is sliding and the background component is inside of the `Modal` component. What you can do here is you can move the background to outside of the modal and show it according to `props.modalVisibility`. Another option would be to use a library that supports what you want, `react-native-modalize`.

Comment: Thanks. WIll give this library a try!